# Metro UI styled libraries for Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, microsoft-metro

I know Microsoft will be releasing Metro UI styles and themes for Silverlight but do any of you already know of similar libraries? I am especially interested in tile animations like those you can see on Windows 8 home screen.

PS: I am not asking about Silverlight metro app themes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah, I'm definitely interested in them too!! You can do everything in XAML - yeah right! You must know how to do it also!

Comment: You might want to take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592326/making-wpf-applications-look-metro-styled-even-in-windows-7-window-chrome-t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Have a look at this!](http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/SLECWMSFSL4)