# Custom window design in VS 2013

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2012, wpf-controls

I want to change the way the window looks and I want it to work on both windows 7 and windows 8. How can i achieve this? I have tried quite a lot but it doesn't look good.

Comment: If you provide specific examples of code that looks different, then we might be able to help.

Comment: `it doesn't look very professional` - professional UIs are `designed` by professional `designers`. Unless you're one, why would your UI look like one?

Comment: @HighCore : I want the design to be a metro-like one, ok?Maybe I didn't use a proper word. As you probably know, on windows 7 the design is aero-oriented. I just wanted to create a custom window(win form) that would look the same on win 7 and 8. If you have seen the window design of Brackets, it keeps the metro look and feel on windows 7. So again, how can I create a custom window desing in wpf?(not a proffesional one :) )

Comment: @AndreiDiaconu do you realize that all the information you posted in this comment should really be part of the question itself? as currently written, your question is completely unclear. Close-voting. Please read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) before posting questions in StackOverflow.

Comment: @HighCore sorry... it's my first question asked on this site. in the future i will be more careful. but can you answer my question? i've seen on you profile page that you are a wpf/xaml guru :) so i think you can easly answer it.

Comment: @AndreiDiaconu see [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15500408/643085).

Comment: thank you! wasn't that hard, right? :)