# Where can i find some themes/demo for UI in WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, themes

I want to design a modern looking UI using visual studio designer in xaml. It gives me a nice toolbox which I can use to create a UI visually by drag and drop. As it is almost behaving like HTML, I was wondering if it too has a rich library of themes. I found some, but they are not editable through designer.
Can someone please help me out and direct me to appropriate links where I can find editable themes for xaml for my WPF project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use this:

**Mahapps.metro** http://mahapps.com/

I very good looking thems and it is free. More info https://stackoverflow.com/a/15500408/5816153

Others:

**Modern UI for WPF (MUI)**  - https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui

And for more info on SO: [Making WPF applications look Metro-styled, even in Windows 7? (Window Chrome / Theming / Theme)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592326/making-wpf-applications-look-metro-styled-even-in-windows-7-window-chrome-t)