# How to create and change app theme in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, themes

I am creating a calculator in WPF and I want to do some themes like light-mode, green-mode and etc. I have menu with options to set theme, and when somebody clicks 'green-mode' the theme should change for green.
I don't know how to start. I want to do it professionally so I think everything should be in XAML. I heard about <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries> and Material Design library. Do you have an idea how to start or what should I read about, any technologies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theming is an extensive topic and there are many resources on this topic out there. Your question actually has two components: how to create a theme, and subsequently, how to have multiple themes and dynamically switch between them.

As for creating themes, I think your best bet would be to take a close look at other themes out there. A theme typically resides in one or more resource dictionaries. A quick search got me this:

- [Where can i find some themes/demo for UI in WPF application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40218843/where-can-i-find-some-themes-demo-for-ui-in-wpf-application)
- https://michaelscodingspot.com/wpf-complete-guide-themes-skins/

Then once you have your themes, add functionality to switch:

- [Change theme at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229724/change-theme-at-runtime)
- http://svetoslavsavov.blogspot.com/2009/07/switching-wpf-interface-themes-at.html

Comment: Thank you so much for help, I will read it and program something.

Comment: Hope it's helpful! If this resolves your question please mark the response as the answer.

Comment: Yes you helped me, thanks, I marked the answer of course.